# Problem with getting user input in Pygame window into 2 separate variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have this code, which allows the user to input something. After pressing return the text field goes blank again and the user is able to input something else. I would like to get these two inputs into 2 different variables, but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
import pygame


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 140, 32)
    color_inactive = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    text = ''
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if input_box1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    active = not active
                else:
                    active = False
                color = color_active if active else color_inactive
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if active:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        print(text)
                        text = ''
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                    else:
                        text += event.unicode

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        width = max(200, txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box1.w = width
        screen.blit(txt_surface, (input_box1.x+5, input_box1.y+5))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_box1, 2)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sadly I haven´t been coding much recently, so I´m very clueless. It was no problem for me to get one input into a variable, by just defining it. But I can´t think of a way of getting the second input into another variable.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I got stuck here: I store the value into a variable and let it print, to check if this works. It all worked fine. But when I enter something new, the variable will change (of course). I can´t think of a way to get around this. And as you can probably see, I´m not very good at python.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I also thought about just adding another input field. I´ll try this but I´m not certain, if my knowledge is enough to do this

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ok got it, finally. But at least thanks for responding

Answer (score -1):

You can save all inputs by appending each input to a list.
First, create an empty list inside the `main` function: `text_list = []`.
Then, inside the `if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:` block, append `text` to `text_list` and print `text_list`.

### Like this:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
    text_list.append(text)
    print(text_list)
    text = ''
```

## Full Code:

```
import pygame


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box1 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 140, 32)
    color_inactive = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
    color_active = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
    color = color_inactive
    active = False
    text = ''
    text_list = []
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if input_box1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    active = not active
                else:
                    active = False
                color = color_active if active else color_inactive
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if active:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        text_list.append(text)
                        print(text_list)
                        text = ''
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                        text = text[:-1]
                    else:
                        text += event.unicode

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        width = max(200, txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        input_box1.w = width
        screen.blit(txt_surface, (input_box1.x+5, input_box1.y+5))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, input_box1, 2)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```